# How to setup a JDBC connection to MySQL in Spring3 MVC?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am working on a small web project in java and Spring3 MVC.  Although I have been studying java for the past 5 months, this is my first time making anything substantial with either of these technologies.

The problem I am having is setting up a Mysql database connection using Dependency Injection in the Spring applicationContext.xml file.

I build a new project in NetBeans and do the following:

1. Include Spring3 with Dependency Injection
2. Import mysql JDBC library
3. Create a jdbc.properties file with associated name value pairs
4. Run project (works fine)
5. Configure Database connection in applicationContext.xml
6. Re load Project
7. Build Fails

This is my applicationContext.xml and jdbc.properties

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->
</beans>
```

This is the jdbc.properties

```
driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bcash
username=root
password=myPassword
```

I have spent the best part of a week trying to configure Spring3, I have also been reading through Spring in Action and Spring Recipes, but I can't seem to get past the first hurdle of just configuring the Spring Container.

Am I overlooking something simple?

Any help is truly appreciated, thanks in advance

UPDATE
Buid error message

```
/home/bcash/NetBeansProjects/bcash.com/nbproject/build-impl.xml:726: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Corresponding build-XML line message

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Comment: "7.Build Fails" - any error messages? Can you query the MySql database from the command line?

Comment: Yeah, thanks Nate, I posted above

Comment: Is this homework? If so you should add the homework-tag to get more appropriate answers.

Comment: It is not homework, in the context of formal education.  I am just trying to learn Java and the Spring MVC framework. I like programming, and I want to improve my skill set.

Comment: Thanks for posting the build error message - there should also be an error message in the server output tab.  The one you posted is basically just the build script saying - "I tried to deploy but something went wrong and I couldn't." The error in the server output should contain more details about what actually failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the advice. I was doing something so blatantly obvious.

I was putting the database connection beans in the wrong xml file.

I was using the appication-context.xml file instead of the dispatcher-servlet.xml file

Thanks anyway guys

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add the connector to your classpath, it's hard to see from your error but it's needed.

If you run tomcat it should be placed in it's /lib directory.

It can be downloaded from [mysql](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mysql%20connector&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQjBAwAQ&url=http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/&ei=ymYgT_OdIOKg4gSqusC9Dw&usg=AFQjCNHT3vMyNb2wZl4BGWYNPA23U8ysag&sig2=yczoAwTN9x2alumrSgzvMg&cad=rja)

or through maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.18</version>
</dependency>
```